# How to convert torch tensor to float?

Tags: python, pytorch

I am using flask to do inference and I am getting this result. Is their any way to convert this tensor into float because I want to use this result to display in a react app

```
{
result: {
predictions: "tensor([[-3.4333]], grad_fn=<AddmmBackward>)"
}
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://newbedev.com/how-do-i-get-value-of-a-tensor-in-pytorch) post, it explains several methods on how to extract values from torch. tensor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [Torch.Tensor.item](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.item.html#torch.Tensor.item) docs:

```
x = torch.tensor([1.0])

print((x.item())
```

output:

```
1.0
```

type check:

```
print(type(x.item())
```

output:

```
float
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use

```py
tensor.to(torch.float)
```